# Can deportation stamp in passport cause problems in the future?

Tags: deportation

I went to China for my internship in a hotel and we extended my student visa for 1 year, also in China. One day the police investigated and told me that I can't work with a student visa and they deported me. My passport got a deportation stamp. Will that passport cause problems if I try to apply for a visa in other countries, like Australia, Canada, Germany?

Answer (score 14):

This is not about a "stamp in the passport". If you've been deported, then yes - it can affect your chances of getting into other countries. Even if you get a new passport and get rid of the stamp, that will not change anything.

For example, on the [Canadian visa application](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5257E.pdf), there's a question - "Have you ever been... ordered to leave Canada **or any other country**". You will have to answer this question truthfully and provide details. (If you lie, it can have very serious consequences, like being banned for many years. Don't think they won't find out, even with a new passport!)

Comment: *Don't think they won't find out, even with a new passport* How would they find out?

Comment: So it's a double edged sword. I doubt China shares details about deportees to any other country. We don't condone lying, but telling the truth about working on a student visa will destroy your chances of getting a visa. However, even if you failed to disclose that deportation, based on your presumed circumstances your chances of getting a visit visa are close to zero. At least for another ten years.

Comment: @MJeffryes they won't. It's easy to be the moral police when you have the high ground but at the end of the day, the OP's decisions should be based on what he believes will yield the best results for him.

Comment: See e.g. http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/laws-policy/agreements/can-usa-agreement.asp for Canada/USA info sharing treaty. While there may not be a Canada/China treaty now, you never know when one might come into effect, and an immigration lie can hurt you many years down the road.

Comment: @EugeneO Yes, we're all aware that allies share this sort of information. But the chances of China sharing it with anyone on that list at any point in the future (other than maybe Australia) is practically nil.

Comment: At the end of the day, you either have a strong reason to want to get into Canada, or you don't. If you have a strong reason (family ties, eventually wanting to immigrate, etc), chances are that the reason is there to stay, and it becomes a long-term play - there were cases of people stripped of citizenship for decades-old lies, and who knows what will be shared with China in 2037 (or even 2020). If you don't have a strong reason to visit - why risk the harsh consequences of lying? By the way, I don't think it's true in Canada, but in the US such lying could technically be a criminal offense.

Comment: By the way, if there's any future immigration intent, Canada will at that time ask for a police certificate from any country where the applicant resided for more than 6 months. I wouldn't be surprised if the Chinese police certificate showed the deportation.

Comment: China sharing such information with any Western country within our lifetimes is zero. That's why any decision should be based on reward vs risk. Even if Canada found out about a failure to declare a previous deportation (for something other than terrorism/serious criminality), prosecution is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, most likely. It shows that you in the past have not been trustworthy to adhere to the conditions of visas previously granted to you.

The stamp itself is not the real problem, but that you have actually been deported. Many countries (including Australia and Canada, but not Germany) ask in the visa application form if you have ever been deported from any country. Even without a stamp in your passport, you will in the future, assumed that you are not intending to lie on a visa application, answer that question with 'yes' and expect that to have consequences for the outcome of your visa application.